# Lightning commandButton calling 2 methods

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, visualforce-component, custom-button

So I would like to have a button call a method and then based on its result call another method. This button will be in lightning and due to some constraints, it needs to be done in visualforce i.e visualforce button. I am causous of using JS as it is not supported in Lightning but I am sure there are some work arounds.

Below is a standard button. It will call a method and that method will return either 0 or 1. If 0 is returned, call the redirect method otherwise display an error message.

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="customObject" extensions="class1">
    <apex:commandButton action="{!method1}" value="Save" id="theButton"/>
</apex:page>
```

Apex Class

```
Global class class1{
WebService static Integer method1(Id recordID)
{
if(data ok) 
    return 0;
else
    return 1;
}
}

//IF 0 IS RETURNED, CALL THIS FUNCTION
public pagereference redirectPage()
{
    try{
    pagereference newPageRef=new pagereference('some link');
    newPageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return newPageRef;
    }
     catch(Exception ex1)
     {        
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex1);
            return null;              
     }   
}
```

I only want 1 button to do this as I am adding it to the page layout. I am unsure how to do this in Visualforce/JS.

Comment: As written, this could just be one function. Why does it need to be two?

Comment: @sfdcfox So the apex class is already in use. So I cannot change method1. However, I need to redirect to a home page if 0 is returned. Is there another way to redirect to another URL? FYI the current button does not work in lightning - this is why I need to develop this

Comment: Are there any alternatives to using block button?